# Mobile app gets closed after first @Test method and gets opened again in Amazon Device Farm

Tags: cordova, amazon-web-services, ionic2, appium, aws-device-farm

-I have used @BeforeSuite for driver creation
-@Test methods for scripts
-@AfterSuite for driver.quit()

But for every @Test method app gets closed and gets opened again.

Answer (score 0):

You should remove the `driver.quit()` from `@AfterSuite`

You can use `driver.quit()` in `@AfterClass` or `@AfterTest`

```
@AfterClass
public void endTest() {
        driver.quit();
    }

@AfterTest
public void endTest() {
          driver.close();
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use **@AfterTest**

The annotated method will be run after all the test methods belonging to the classes inside the **@test** tag have run.
If you want to learn more about annotations click [TestNG annotations](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/testng/testng_basic_annotations.htm)